# Multiple Audio CD Burning On Linux

Tags: linux, cd-burning

Have not been able to get a definitive answer on this. Using cdrecord or cdrdao on a linux box is it possible to write 4 different audio CDs at the same time.

System is a P4 2.4 800fsb The drives are all on 2 IDE Channels.

Edit:
To clarify the audio CDs are all different so its not a 1 image to 4 Duplication kinda deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically yes.  Practically probably not.

You can certainly run 4 `cdrecord` processes at once but the likelyhood that you will get [`buffer underrun`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_underrun) is quite high.

To get an even more definitive answer I'd just try to do it.